# Spring Cloud Kafka Streams - Application up but logs suggest kafka streams not running

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

We are running a spring cloud application using spring-cloud-kafka-streams. Application is connected to kafka-cluster of 3 nodes, but whenever any one node comes down, application keeps running, but gets warning in logs -

> WARNING: [Consumer clientId=kaas.alpha.app-transformer-service-929ab2e7-99c3-4ae2-ae70-18d5426d2c9d-StreamThread-1-consumer, groupId=kaas.alpha.app-transformer-service] Connection to node -2 could not be established. Broker may not be available.

On querying one of the materialized state-store, it errors out with kafka streams is not running.

Comment: We will take a look at this. How do you query the materialized store when the node is down?

Comment: Rest API, which calls this function -  `public GenericRecord getRecordFromStore(String id, String stateStore) {
        final ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, GenericRecord> store = interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(stateStore, QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore());
        return store.get(id);
    }`